# WC()->cart->get_cart() shows empty but not on cart page

Tags: php, android, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a PHP script on a WooCommerce webserver that interfaces with an Android app I am developing. I mainly use it for logging into Wordpress accounts and adding/removing products to the WooCommerce cart.

These functions work just fine:

```
function add_to_cart(){
    return WC()->cart->add_to_cart(
        $_POST['product_id'], 
        $_POST['quantity'],
        $_POST['variation_id'],
        null, 
        null);
}

function remove_from_cart(){
    if(empty($_POST['cart_item_key'])){
        return 'Please specify cart_item_key';
    }
    WC()->cart->remove_cart_item($_POST['cart_item_key']);
    return 'Product removed from cart!';
}
```

This function also works, but it return an empty array...

```
function get_cart_contents(){
    return WC()->cart->get_cart();
}
```

However I know that the cart is not empty because when I add a product to the cart on the app it shows in the cart on the website. Is there a different function I should be calling? Am I forgetting to call something?

### *I'm on a learn-implement basis with PHP, constructive criticism welcome*

Comment: does this happens with a user logged in or not?

Comment: `interfaces with an Android app` <- This is the key. How are you doing that? Have you looked into the REST API?

Comment: May be try [get_cart_from_session( )](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_get_cart_from_session) method

Comment: @Reigel Yes the user cannot view the cart unless logged in.

Comment: @NathanDawson I use the REST API as well, but it does not have support for cart functionality so I have to use PHP for that.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, I tried that. It returns null.

Comment: in that case you have session problem...

Comment: Also may be **try to rename your functions** are they are very near from woocommerce methods and functions names.